# Is there a way to set the content of each page on ngx-typed-js?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the TypedJS version for Angular [ngx-typed-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-typed-js) to print the content of a container, but I'm having a huge problem when the content gets more than one page, cutting off the content in the middle of those.

Is there a way to control the content of each page ? Or some kind of preview?

Here is a screenshot of the problem and the package page on the NPM website.

[image]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-typed-js

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution in a property name page-break-before.

> "The page-break-before property adds a page-break before the element to which it is applied."

```
page-break-before: always;
```

[page-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)